# How do I "stub" a child ember component in an integration test?

Tags: testing, ember.js, integration-testing, qunit

Say I have a component A that contains component B. I'm writing an integration test for component A, but component B is an addon which I don't want to include with the tests (mainly because it makes xhr requests that I'd rather keep out of my integration test). Is there any documentation on how to do this? Or does anyone have a best practice?

Comment: You could always mock the ajax call.

Comment: I could, but I'd rather not do that in an integration test since I'm not really testing that component...

Comment: Yeah, that sounds more like a Unit test than an integration test then :)

Comment: Well a unit test would be more if I'm testing individual methods in my component, right? I want to test the component as a whole, but not a component nested inside of it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. If I were in this situation I would use sinon to intercept the request. Alternately, make your component compose able by using it in block form and just don't instantiate the child in the template in your test